# how to iterate over all specified hosts

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that is supposed to create a config file for all specified hosts, on my monitoring_sever.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True

  hosts: monitoring_server
  tasks:
  - command: touch {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}
    with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

I execute the playbook with `ansible-playbook main.yml -l "new_client, new_client2, monitoring_server"`

The Resulting files on the monitoring server should look like the following:
    client1.conf client2.conf

But I get an error about missing quotes, I've tried all sorts of syntax changes but I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
    - file:
        path: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}"
        state: touch
      delegate_to: host_name # Delegate task to specific host
      with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

You have typos in your original playbook.

1. `with:items` should be `with_items`
2. `items` should be `item`

Usage of `delegate_to`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

---

As long as you are targeting all hosts, you don't have to make a loop as Ansible executes tasks on all targeted hosts unless excluded by condition.

On the other hand, I would suggest using `file` module instead of `command` to touch the file.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Touch a file
      file:
        path: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"
        state: touch
```

PS. I assumed `ansible_fqdn` is a host var you defined for each host.

Comment: The problem is that I want to create the files for all hosts but only on the monitoring_server. I only used touch for debug reasons the original task is to copy a config file using template.

Comment: Consider elaborate more clearly in your question. I will update my answer as well.

Comment: For that, @David, just add `delegate_to: localhost` on the task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix:

1. `with_items:` instead of `with:items:`
2. `item` instead of `items`
3. a single `hosts:` declaration in each item on the list of plays

This should work for your case:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

- hosts: monitoring_server
  tasks:
    - command: touch {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}
      with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

---

Alternatively you can use `delegate_to: localhost` and completely drop the loop as well as the reference to `hostvars`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - command: touch {{ ansible_fqdn }}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected items to item in my playbook. The double host declaration is necessary though since it has to retrieve the variable from the other systems using gather_facts.

Comment: YAML doesn't work this way. If you need to gather facts, you need to have two items, not one.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still getting an error even when I'm copying and executing the example you've send me and i just can't figure out why. I've executed the playbook using `ansible-playbook test.ym -l "new_client1, monitoring_server"``the error is the following: `the field 'args' has an invalid value.[...] line 7, column 7`

Comment: @David The example I included has 6 lines. How do you think I am able to tell what is in your line no. 7?

Comment: the error i've included was from your first example and there is nothing else in the playbook. But the second example did not work either.

Comment: You need to debug yourself. I have no access to your systems and have no way of knowing what value `ansible_fqdn` is set in your case? Most likely it's not set at all, and that's why you get an error. I see no relation to the question.